# chanding scene in javafx scene bulider

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a  loading page in javafx scenebuilder  but I get an  error on  the line rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane),it underlines  etChildren() and says it doesnt find the symbol,dont understant why that is.

```
package javafxapplication14;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private Label label;

    private Object theStage;
    private Object rootPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

    private void loadsecond(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Second.fxml"));
        rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }
}
```

Comment: *it underlines etChildren()* - do you mean "*getChildren()*"?

Comment: yes its  getChildren() ,sorry I misspell that

Comment: `Object` does not contain a `getChildren()` method. Use the proper type for the field.

Answer (score 0):

The class [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) can't handle `.getChildren()`.

Comment: In class we did something similar were we took the FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Second.fxml")); so it can load the senond scene when you click on a button from a diffrent scene.It work then ,I guess I have miss a import point in the process.

Comment: Shouldn't your rootPane be a Pane?

Comment: rootPane is  tha id I gave  the   AnchorPane

Comment: Then it needs to be one `AnchorPane`, not `Object`.

Comment: Yeah your right ,it should